# Update private data collection policy in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

From docs:

> To configure the chaincode collections on the channel, specify the
>   flag --collections-config along with the name of the collections JSON
>   file,

Is it possible to update private data collection policy after instantiation of the channel? In my case I want to add a member or remove a member from policy for a particular private data collection.

Or if there is another approach, I would like hear it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, there is a peer chain code upgrade command that can be used after instantiation.

> Refer:  [peer chaincode upgrade](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/commands/peerchaincode.html?highlight=chaincode%20upgrade#peer-chaincode-upgrade)

where you can specify --collections-config flag with your new collections-config file by either adding or removing member from a policy.

Your second question on another approach, If you want to add/remove members you can consider creating a new channel but that depends on your usecase. For this you can refer to

> [When to use a collection within a channel vs. a separate channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data/private-data.html#when-to-use-a-collection-within-a-channel-vs-a-separate-channel)

Comment: What about the state? I see in example usage, during chaincode upgrade `init` argument is passed. Does that mean the whole state is re-initialised. I might be missing something here, enlighten me.

Comment: Yes we need to init the chaincode everytime we upgrade, but no, the new chaincode will immediately replace the existing chaincode upon the transaction committed so it does not init the state again, so previous data can be used. You can update a chaincode to change the chaincode's programming while maintaining its relationship to the assets on the ledger.